# Unexpected gap right of header and footer when both are set with width:100%?

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

When using my phone to view a website i'm creating the site appears and seems to act differently than i expect?

I have a screenshot to demonstrate the problem on said smartphone screen.

*Smartphone view*

[image: screenshot]

As you can see both the header and footer are not expanding 100% in width as they should, and do when viewed using a desktop browser.

*Desktop view*

[image: screenshot]

**Header CSS**

```
#banner {

    background-image: url(images/images/bannersketchBG.jpeg);
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-style: italic;
}

#banner1 {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 24pt;
    top: 0px;
}

#banner2 {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 410px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**Footer CSS**

```
.footer {
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
    word-spacing: normal;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;

}
```

**HTML**

*Header*

```
 <div align="center">
          <div id="banner">
          <div id="logo"><img src="images/Joel-Compass-black.png" width="119" height="95" alt="CCFS"></div>
            <div id ="banner1">Columbus Car Finder Group</div>
            <div id ="banner2">"Exploring your Needs"</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

*Footer*

```
<div class="footer">

<div class="footercontainer">


   <div id="footerTabsContainer">
     <div class='tab one'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Find My Car</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
      <div class='tab two'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='tab three'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
       <div class='tab three'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='tab five'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class='tab six'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>

    </div>
    <div class="footerinfo">Web Design - <a href="index.html">CundyTech </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Copyright South West Car Finder 2013</div>
     </div>

    </div>
```

I notice the background image cuts off at the same point too, so could this be an overflow issue?!

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

PS i know i haven't quite got the finer points of css like using ID's and Classes properly but i am still learning so please dont hate on me too much!

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well please?

Comment: the whole page or just snippets of header and footer? It's quite lengthy and probably not the easiest to work out what is going on.

Comment: Just the snippets of the header and footer please.

Comment: I suspect the problem doesn't come from footer or header, but from the content between them. Without the whole code it's going to be hard to answer. Can you try making a simple fiddle that redoes the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set div to width 100%, it expands by default. What you can try is to remove width property (from footer and header) and set min-width to be the same as your content's (it is a fixed width right?).

Do you have a link to the website that we can access? It is easy to test what works with Chrome/Firefox developer tools.

Comment: FYI, The footer is acting weird as i'm trying to implement a sticky footer solution, but have not succeeded as of yet.

Comment: Your layout is broken because of the float: left property that you apply to everything. You have to redesign and not apply float left to everything. Div is by default 100% width, 0 padding, 0 margin. What you need to do is to set height to your divs (as it seems you want these of fixed height.

Comment: what should i apply float to? I have taught my self from scratch and admit i have just been sticking with floating everything as it seems to work.

Comment: Float makes div not expand. By default div has 100% width, the time you float it, it has the width of it's content. The problem is when you have div container and div child. You float div child but not the container, now div container will always have 0 height even if you set some height to the child. If you have all the children floated, container will be 0 height. It is strange and I had hard time understanding it myself but when you work with that a little you will get used to this. I wrote an example that might be of some help: http://jsfiddle.net/2bvNC/4/

Comment: So I've sorted the issues you mentioned. Header and Footer and not floated, neither is container, content inside container is floated though. so is all fine. It is the gaps i'm getting right of my header and footer though that is still the problem. Neither are set to 100% width either.

Comment: Make your body element `min-width: 1003px`. Your container has `width: 1000px` + some other styles that gives `1003px`. If you want your website fully responsive then you should now use [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). Making your website fully responsive means to make it collapse to the width of the device and a `width: 1000px` is too much for mobile.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of min-width! That sorted the gap on the right of the header and foot out perfectly! Also I did start to implement media queries halfway through this current project but it got to complicated maintaining all the different Style Sheets. I think i'll either retrofit them after i'm finished this projects or keep them in mind for the next.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when your content isn't enough to fill up the screen. I personally use `calc()` to sort it out. You can try this.

```
.your_header{
  height:100px;
}
.your_content{
  min-height:calc(100% - 300px);
}
.your_footer{
  height:200px;
}
```

What it does is that it calculates `min-height` for `your_content` to 100% - height of your header - height of your footer;

Comment: Is calc fully supported?

Comment: this is a similar solution to a sticky footer i believe, this is a problem i'm having but not related to the question i have asked. (i think) it is the width of the footer and header not filling the screen 100% on a mobile that is getting the best of me.

Comment: @DanCundy: This isn't sticky footer. It will just kick in when your content isn't enough to fill up the space.

Comment: @LokeshSuthar the problem isn't filling the gap between the content and footer (height-wise). The problem is there is a gap to the right of both the header and footer where there shouldn't be. There isn't a gap to the right on the content div.

Answer (score 0):

Don't float your #banner or .footer. Check this cool tutorial on positioning to get a better idea: [CSS Learn Positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: I have now Float:none and no width set, and still the problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Change the positioning of the footer to be fixed.

```
positioning: fixed; // will make the footer stick to the base of the viewport.
right: 0; // fill space to right
bottom: 0;  // stick to the bottom of page
left: 0; // fill space to left
```

Notice we left out the top attribute... this is because we want that to be set automatically by the height of the inner elements.

You may also want to try `position: absolute;` and tweak the bottom padding on the body to give a result that will clear the body content and not stick to the viewport.

This should get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: would i be right in saying if i changed the footer positioning to fixed, when the browsers height changed the footer would remain bottom:0; but it would also overlap content thus hiding things underneath?

Comment: yeah correct, if that is not desired use absolute or relative

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Linek in his answer, in the comments, adding a min-width style to body will solve this problem. I also had to add a min-width to the header, not sure why body didn't do both though?

**Solution**

> Css

```
Body
{
min-width:1003px;
}
```